# Get entry text from wxTextCtrl in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, wxwidgets

I have this piece of code:

```
void stoiximanFrame::OnButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    cout<< TextCtrl1.GetValue() <<endl;

}
```

I just want to get the text from TextCtrl1 and I get this error:

> > stoiximanFrame::TextCtrl1’, which is of pointer type ‘wxTextCtrl*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)

I'm new to C++ so I've never used pointers before. I've read the basics of pointers but still I couldn't figure out how to solve the problem above.

In addition, I would appreciate any good documentation about how and when to use pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: [FAQ C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextCtrl1` seems to be a pointer to an object of class `wxTextCtrl`(also `wxTextCtrl*`). By using the arrow operator `->` you access the public members of the object the pointer is pointing to. It is a shortcut for using dereferencation(`*`) and member access(`.`).

This means `TextCtrl1->GetValue()` is equivalent to `(*TextCtrl1).GetValue()`

So just do what your compiler says and write

```
cout << TextCtrl1->GetValue() << endl;
```

to solve your problem.

If you are new to C++ i recommend you to read about pointers. For example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) because that's one of the major differences to other languages.

Comment: Wow, C++ seems so different from other programming languages. "->" is really unprecedented for me. Thanks for this useful clarification.